# Is Buddhism on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Corresponding to the [question concerning atheism/agnosticism](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/is-atheism-agnosticism-proposal-on-topic-in-philoshophy-here): Do we consider practical questions on Buddhism like [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/definition-and-scope-of-dukkha) on-topic here?

I don't mean to ban every question on Buddhism, many of those seemed to at least relate to other philosophical question, like [Is Buddhism a religion or philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3428/is-buddhism-a-religion-or-philosophy) or [What would an economics that takes buddhism seriously look like?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/what-would-an-economics-that-takes-buddhism-seriously-look-like) But questions that are only concerned with the interpretation of purely buddhist concepts and notions - I don't see how they belong here (btw., hopefully there will be a Buddhism Site [soon](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism).

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [mentioned this in passing in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7538741#7538741) the other week. Not sure what people's feelings are about these questions (a handful of people seem to like them, as a number of those questions that I would consider off-topic are getting upvotes), but to me if they are about ***practicing*** Buddhism, they are off-topic. If they are about some ***philosophical notion*** of Buddhism, they are on-topic (i.e., the same criteria we have for Christianity and other "religious" questions).